# Iptables/ufw - blocking ports when using nat

Tags: iptables, nat, ufw, proxmox

I use NAT to move requests from external ports to an internal ip address and port hosted with proxmox.

Something like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.1:80
```

However even when I try to temporarily block port 8000 the requests still go through and I can access the web pages.

Can you not block ports on the host machine when using NAT? Do I have to do this on the virtual machine? Is this just the wrong command? `ufw deny 8000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using portforwarding in the PREROUTING chain, so you have to use Port blocking in the FORWARD chain on the host system or block the port in the INPUT chains of the guest system.

But it's easier to delete the portfording rule to make the website inaccessible

Look at this chart to understand how the `IPTables Chain Order` works:

http://www.ironflake.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Linux_IptablesSchema.png